# Python debugging by invoking the keyboardinput in a script

Tags: python, debugging, keyboard, invoke

ys it possible to invoke the keyboard in a python script?
E.g. in MATLAB there is way to write

```
% A lot of code "A"
...
keyboard
% A lot of code "B"
...
```

in a script, so if you execute the script, it will halt at "keyboard" and you can go on in your MATLAB-shell with the workspace which was build up by code in "A".
Is there a similar command in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Python debugger](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html); instead of `keyboard` you'd use:

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

and the debugger stops execution and lets you investigate the state of your program.

Comment: If you use ipython, there's also ipdb which runs pdb in the ipython interface.  Similar invocation as well `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()`.  It's a separate package tho, available in PyPI.

Comment: Nice, it is excactly what i was looking for